# Taylor expansion of $\left(x+a-\sqrt{x(x+2a)}\right)^{\alpha}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

I would like to obtain the Taylor expansion of $\color{red}{g(x)=\left(x+a-\sqrt{x(x+2a)}\right)^{\alpha}}$ at $\color{blue}{x=x_0>0}$. Here, $a>0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Note that

$$\left(x+a-\sqrt{x(x+2a)}\right)^{\alpha}=\left(x+a-\sqrt{(x+a)^2-a^2}\right)^{\alpha}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+2a}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)^{2\alpha}$$

Since calculate the n$th$ derivative of $g(x)$ is complicated, I wonder if is possible to get a closed form for this n$th$ derivative (I don't know) or use a known series of another related function (Which? How?).

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: don't know -- but perhaps expanding $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2a}$ into Taylor series around $x$ would work, i.e. $f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + h^2 f''(x)/2! \ldots$ for $h=2a$?

Comment: this may help $Faà di Bruno's formula$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: @logo I just tried use Fa di Bruno formula but it's very complicated

Comment: Taylor expansion for the  composition of two functions is complicated in general!!!

Comment: the coefficient of the general term in the series centered at $x={{x}_{0}}$   is given by (using Mathematica) [see this image] (https://ibb.co/MMdwQBT)  ...but i don't know how to explain it???